# Как определить объект в пространстве имен?

Tags: wpf

Пытаюсь организовать привязку...
**Подскажите что я сделал неправильно?**

> **Ошибка:** Свойство PersonName не найдено в типе Person

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="pr2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:pr2"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <src:Person x:Key="myDataSource" PersonName="Joe"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=PersonName}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace pr2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string PersonName;       
    }
}
```

В MSDN написано:

> Объект Person определен в пространстве имен с именем pr2

**Каким образом его нужно определить?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PersonName` должно быть свойством. Т.е. нужно преобразовать Ваш код в следующий:

```
public string PersonName{get; set;};
```

Comment: ...И скорее всего ещё имплементировать INPC.